# Is there any way to integrate Express route with Azure function or service fabric using private IP Address?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have one cloud service which communicates with Express route with private IP address. I want to migrate this to an Azure Function or Service Fabric but due to private IP address I am unable to migrate cloud service. Is there any way to integrate Azure Function or Service Fabric with cloud service using private IP address (I cant use public address because of security reasons)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run Azure Functions inside a virtual network. See here for the different options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options

[image]

Also Service Fabric can be deployed inside a private VNET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-patterns-networking

Comment: basically, what this answer is trying to tell you - use a regular app service plan, not a consumption plan. as for the SF, there is no way to deploy it without private IP.

Comment: Well as the matrix shows, app service plan is only one option. It really depends on what exactly the OPs requirements are. App Service plan would be the cheapest option, yes, but premium plan or ASE might match his scenario better. We don't know from how the question was written.